# Kafka consumer failure detection

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

A simple kafka client to test consumer failure detection does not provide expected behavior. I must have missed something.

Tested with kafka version 0.10.1.0 and consumer with java kafka-client 0.10.1.0.

Following class is lunch two times in parallel. As expected, one client is consuming the topic in the group. But if the active consumer is killed with kill -9, the group is not rebalanced to the other consumer.

```
public class BasicConsumer {

    public BasicConsumer() {
        // set up the consumer
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers",       "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id",                "test");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit",      "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms",      "30000"); // half a minute timeout
        props.put("max.poll.records",        "10");
        props.put("key.deserializer",        "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer",      "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        System.out.printf("Starting Consumer %n");

        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test1"));

        LocalDateTime inFewMinutes = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(10);
        try {
            while (LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(inFewMinutes)) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
                System.out.printf("%s Poll returned %d records%n", LocalDateTime.now(), records.count());
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
                    Map    message = new Gson().fromJson(record.value(), Map.class);
                    Map    data    = (Map<String, String>) message.get("data");
                    String msgId   = (String)              data.get("TRANSFER_ID");

                    System.out.printf("%s Handling record id %s with offset %s%n", LocalDateTime.now(), msgId, record.offset());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
            System.out.printf("Consumer closed cleanly...%n");
        }
    }
}
```

The kafka and zookeeper servers are straightforward installation without any modification in configuration.

Thanks in advance for any idea.

**late edition** : question is resolved

To kill the consumer, i stopped the **gradle run** command used to launch the java client. This actually doesn't stop the java process...

Killing correctly the java process shows that in the logs, a delay of 30 seconds appears between the active consumer being killed and the rebalancing made with kafka to give the hand to the second consumer. As expected by the session.timeout.ms parameter.

Comment: Since the session.timeout.ms is set to 30 seconds, so coordinator might wait up to 30 seconds to be aware of the failure. Could you observe whether it happens after a complete session timeout passes?

Comment: The consumer is polling the kafka topic for 10mn before exiting. This session.timeout.ms parameter would trigger rebalancing if it had any effect. This is not the case, the remaining customer is still receiving 0 records for the remaining 10mn time after the fist customer was killed.

Comment: You cannot say the rebalance fails only by the fact that polling returns nothing. That's a separate issue that is probably due to the default value for config ''auto.offset.reset" set to "largest".

Comment: I found what was wrong... The java consumer was launched with a "gradle run" commande. To kill the consumer, i stopped the gradle process. This actually doesn't stop the java process. The stdout redirection on the gradle command line was also stopped with the gradle process... The utility bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh helped me to identify the problem. I will make more tests and close this topic. Tanks a lot for the comments.